# If span contains ID then

Tags: jquery, checkbox, this

I am having a difficulty when trying to make an if-statement with `$(this).attr("id")`. Want I want is that when a checkbox is clicked AND checked, its ID is logged in a div `#log` (this works). When it is clicked and not checked, jQuery should check whether a logged line is the same as the ID of the checkbox. If so, that span should get removed.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fLskG/1/

So when you click `Option 1` the text `option-0` will appear (this is the checkbox's ID). When you click the button again, that text should disappear.

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").find("input:checkbox").click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#textValue").text($(this).val());
            $("#log").append("<span>" + this.id + "</span><br/>");
        }
        else {
            if ($("#log").children("span").contains($(this).attr("id"))) {
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                $("#log").children("span").remove();
            }
        }
    });
});​
```

I  am quite sure the problem lies with the 'contains'. But I don't know how to make jQuery check whether there is a span which contains the ID of the checkbox checked in the first function.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could adopt the HTML5 data attribute, but since it's one-to-one, I just went with giving the span an id of `log-{checkbox-id}`, so basically:

```
$(".menu input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#textValue").text($(this).val());
        $("#log").append("<span id=\"log-" + this.id + "\">" + this.id + "</span><br/>");
    }
    else {
        $("#log-" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
    }
});​
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/fLskG/7/

The nice thing with this is that you don't have to confirm if the value already is in the list, since it just won't be found with the selector. I would probably tighten up how you did the insert and HTML as well, but for now, I just wanted to modify the code enough to show the id tag solution.

Here it is, a bit tightened up:

```
$(".menu input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#textValue").text($(this).val());
        var $log_entry = $('<li>');
        $log_entry.attr("id", "log-" + this.id);
        $log_entry.text(this.id);
        $("#log").append($log_entry);
    }
    else {
        $("#log-" + $(this).attr("id")).remove();
    }
});​
```

Notice that the log is now a `ul` so no need for a break, etc, making it easier to add the id attribute and text. New demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/crazytonyi/fLskG/12/

Comment: Thanks a lot. Nice find of the ul as well! Just wondering, do you have any idea what's the difference between this.id and $(this).attr("id")? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was wondering that too, then it just hit me. `this.id` is the actual DOM object (which has a property `id`), while `$(this)` is the jquery object, which uses the `attr()` method to get attributes for all elements matching the selector and doesn't have a native property for the specific id.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$("#log").children("span").contains($(this).attr("id"))` use `$('#log span:contains("'+ this.id +'")')`.

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").find("input:checkbox").click(function() {

```
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("#textValue").text($(this).val());
        $("#log").append("<span>" + this.id + "</span><br/>");
    }
    else {
        $('#log span:contains("'+ this.id +'")').next('br').andSelf().remove();
    }
});
```

});

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fLskG/10/)**

Comment: Your code removes all the spans under `#log`. I don't think that's what the asker is looking for.

Comment: Your code still isn't quite right. The `if` will always be true because a jQuery object will always be returned. Get rid of the `if` altogether, and just do the remove. If no elements are matched, no harm done.

Answer (score 1):

just check this. i think you have to remove only the unchecked checkbox's span

http://jsfiddle.net/fLskG/6/

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu").find("input:checkbox").click(function() {

        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $("#textValue").text($(this).val());
            $("#log").append("<span>" + this.id + "</span><br/>");
        }
        else {
            if ($("#log").children("span:contains("+($(this).attr("id"))+")")) {
                console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                $("#log").children("span:contains("+($(this).attr("id"))+")").remove();
            }
        }
    });
});
```